# SonarQube Background Tasks Not Running

Tags: background, sonarqube, task

I installed Sonarqube 5.2 and integrated it with TFS 2013 to analyse C# code. The build is executed successfully and the runner analysis is sent to sonarqube server, but...

the background task on sonar never starts. It doesn't fail, it's just pending forever.

Is there any configuration, that I may have missed?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Can you have a look at this similar question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33552845/sonarqube-analysis-succeeds-but-isnt-processed-by-server) and its answer.

Looks like a common problems with Sonarqube 5.2. If you had conditions (coverage on new code) defined for multiple periods (since previous version, since previous analysis, for last 30 days) in youe quality gates. It worked like a charm before, now it's broken.